# Migrating and comparing a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization, compare, redgate, migrating

We downloaded today RedGate's Toolbet, in oder to automatize some tasks that take so long in our company when it comes to databases.

The first one appear with a 15 GB database we have, with a lot of indexes, constrains and also several triggers. We want this database to be migrated exactly with the schema, all the data, triggers, etc to a new DB with the idea to reduce the size an also to get a better performance hidding all the mistakes commited in the past. Unfortunately this was the first customer's release DB of one products, and we used it to test lot of things that no always worked pretty well. We are sure that if we do something like this, we will get more tha 50% of the size back into our disk.

Can one or some Toolbet tools combined be useful to do this? If answer is not, is there available other tool useful for this task?

Comment: what do you mean by "Clean Database"?

Comment: What are you migrating from and migrating to?

Answer (score 0):

One common way this can happen is if you are not selecting all your tables to be included in the compare. For example, you may have selected a child table and not the parent table. This could lead to a FK error like you describe.